# Proving that a group of order $p^n$ has a center consisting of more than one element.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove the following:

> If $G$ is a group of order $p^n$ where $n\geq 1$ and $p$ is a prime number, then the center of $G$ contains more than one element.

Consider the group $G=\{-1,0,1\}$ where the operation is $-$ (subtraction). Also, $2=-2=0$. It is easy to check that this is a group. $|G|=3$ and the center consists only of $\{0\}$. Isn't this a contradiction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Subtraction is not a group operation. There is no neutral element for that.

Comment: An element $e$ such that $e \odot a = a = a \odot e$ for all $a$, where $\odot$ is the operation.

Comment: Subtraction is not even associative.

Comment: This might seem like an insignificant comment, but subtraction is a group operation in the trivial group $\{e\}$. But then again, I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the class equation $$|G|=|Z|+\sum [G:C(x_i)]$$

Then $|G|$ and $[G:C(x_i)]$ are all positive powers of $p$ (why?). If $|Z|=1$, consider modding out by $p$.